# My CSS navigation bar won't move up or down, and break when I try to

Tags: html, css

I'm new to HTML and CSS, I started like a week ago, and now I'm having trouble moving this navigation bar I generated with a website. When I try to use `margin-bottom` or `margin-top`, the whole navigation bar completely extends, but doesn't move. I've tried using `position: absolute` and try to set the postition like that, but then completely collapses, but it does seem to move.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="mainmenu">
 <ul> 
 <li><a class=current href="/index.html"> Home</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/lesmiserbales.html">Les Miserables</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/chicago.html">Chicago</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/shrek.html">Shrek</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/phtanomoftheopera.html">Phantom Of The Opera</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/wicked.html">Wicked</a></li>
 <li><a  href="tickets.html">Tickets</a></li> 
 <li><a  href="/htfs.html">How To Find Us</a></li>
 <li><a  href="/contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
 </ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.mainmenu a {

color: #ffffff;
border: 0px solid;
background-color: #302E2E;
padding-left: 4px;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
padding-right: 4px;
font: 12px Arial;
font-weight: normal;
text-decoration: none;
border-color: #000000;
display: block;
margin: 0px;
width: 100px;
text-align: left;
z-index:2;
position: absolute;
top: 50px;
}

.mainmenu a:visited { color: #ffffff; }

.mainmenu a:hover {
border: 0px solid;
padding-left: 4px;
padding-top: 4px;
padding-bottom: 4px;
padding-right: 4px;
background-color: #333030;
border-color: #000000;
color: #000000;
font: 12px Arial;
font-weight: normal;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: left;
display: block;
width: 100px;

 }


 .mainmenu ul {
list-style:none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;

 }

.mainmenu li {

margin: 0;
    padding-top: 1px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, and sorry if I made a rookie mistake or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove : position: absolute from your css.

Add the fallowing in your css:

```
.mainmenu {
margin-top: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS is positioning each menu item not the menu itself.
Remove `position: absolute;` and `top: 50px;` from `.mainmenu a` and put it in a new declaration for `.mainmenu`

```
.mainmenu a {
    ...
    /*
    GET RID OF THESE:
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px; 
    */
}

/* ADD THIS */
.mainmenu {        
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
}
```

Just like I have done in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QJN9H/)

Comment: Thanks to you too! The other guy was first, but thank you for explaining what I did wrong :)